# Cannot start session if documents are in different encoding

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I think i encountered a PHP bug 
When my header file is in UTF-8 encoding and my index.php file is in ANSI  PHP gives 
" headers already sent " error .
Is this normal ? and if yes , can you explain why ?

Comment: Are you sure you're sending any headers before you've output anything to the browser?

Comment: I'm telling ya .. one moment is working , net i change the encoding , F5 , showing headers error , converting back to ANSII > F5 , Working ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your editor is writing a UTF-8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) to the beginning of the "header" file, and PHP, not knowing what the BOM is, considers it as data to output and does that annoying thing PHP does?

There's a [long-standing WONTFIX bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22108) on PHP's mis-handling of the BOM. Probably your only workaround is to find an editor that writes UTF-8 without it (which, actually, is most of them.)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before. Somewhere outside of the  the encoding is generating some whitespace. It was a pain and a half to track down.